# Using Navicat to Browse large databases with many tables

Tags: mysql, navicat

I have been working with Navicat MySQL to manage our company database for our web application.

This application has grown quite a bit, we have 2 main databases, 1 for configurations and settings, other database includes 500,000+ tables of individual reporting devices.

**Any tricks or tips to enable the quicker load of that database?** It takes 5 - 10 minutes for the database to open so the information can be browsed.

Thanks in Advanced,

Comment: Ever get anywhere with this? I have the same issue with Navicat on Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I figured it out. Best way is to copy your profile and in the Edit connection -> Advanced tab choose advanced settings and select only your database. This allows for the -a option when working with command line.

Hope it helps!